# How can this src vs. build tree timestamp comparison be faster?

Tags: java, bash, makefile, timestamp, directory-tree

```
for n in `cd src; find . -name "*.java"; cd -`;
  do a=`echo $n | cut -d '.' -f2`;
  if [[ src/$a.java -nt build/$a.class ]];
    then echo src/$a.java;
  fi;
done
```

It lists all the java files in the src tree; then for each one, it removes the suffix ".java" (`cut -d '.' -f2` because `find .` output is prefixed with `.`). It then uses `-nt` to test if the java file in the src tree is newer than the corresponding class file in the build tree; if it is newer, it is output.  [javac can then use this to compile only the needed src files, instead of using `ant` or `make`]

The problem is that it is too slow, taking about 275ms.  How to make it faster?

Or is there a faster way to do this in bash?  I can't see how to do it with `find`, `diff`, `rsync` nor `make` (which doesn't seem to traverse trees automatically, and needs explicitly listed source files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for f in src/*.java; do 
  file=`basename $f`; 
  if [[ src/$file -nt build/${file//.java/} ]]; then 
     echo src/$file; 
  fi; 
done
```

Comment: That won't recursively process subdirs of src though.

Comment: I think you mean ${file/.java/.class} in the substitution?

Comment: Thanks, I like the `basename $f` and `${file//.java/}` - I didn't know them!  In the latter, I think you meant `build/${file/.java/.class}`.  But `src/*.java` and `basename` only cover one level, not a src tree (e.g. nested packages).

Comment: Sorry @martin and @Douglas, I didn't refresh before commenting. At least we're in agreement. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this structure would be any faster, but it might be worth a try:

```
while read n
do
     # capture the basename all at once
     [[ $n =~ src/(.*)\.java ]]   # escape the parentheses for Bash < 3.2 (or thereabouts)
     [[ $n -nt "build/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.class" ]] && echo $n
done < <(find src -name "*.java")
```

The `while` form probably won't provide any boost. The collapsed `if` may. The regex might provide a small contribution.

As you've found out, eliminating a call to `cut` has made the biggest difference.

Comment: what bash version are you using? maybe it doesn't support the binary operator =~

Comment: `=~` was introduced in 3.0 and there were changes that affect compatibility somewhere around 3.1 or 3.2

Comment: Please note that I had the wrong index to $BASH_REMATCH. It's now fixed.

Comment: @13ren: Try escaping the parantheses: `[[ $n =~ src/\(.*\)\.java ]]` if you have Bash < 3.2

Comment: @Dennis bash version 3.1.17(1) here.  Escaping the parentheses fixed the syntax error.  It's not listing the newer files though... it's now working with added `.class` to `"build/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.class"` and the `cd src` moved into the `find`, as in: `(find src -name "*.java")`.  It's averaging around 65ms - much faster than the original; but not as fast as the 45ms one above.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting kon's approach to the filename munging, the speed improves from 320ms to 45ms on average. Thanks kon!

```
for n in `cd src; find . -name "*.java"; cd -`; do
  if [[ src/$n -nt build/${n/.java/.class} ]];
     then echo src/$n;
  fi;
done
```

The original is a bit slower now (was 275ms; now 320ms); I don't know why. I'm using the same line. Maybe different system sources after playing a video.

*EDIT* re rst's comment: mangling the "src/" away instead of `cd src;` ... `cd -;`.  Note that both `$n` and `$n2` are used [you can't nest the ${var/A/B} construct, can you?]

```
for n in `find src -name "*.java"`; do
  n2=${n/src/}
  if [[ $n -nt build/${n2/.java/.class} ]];
     then echo $n;
  fi;
done
```

Comment: I don't think the `; cd -` is needed here.

Comment: @rsp I agree.  The `; cd -` reverses the `cd src;`, which was needed so the same path fragment could appear in both src and build trees.  I'll update this answer with name mangling instead.

Comment: The reason the `; cd -` is not needed is that the `cd src; find...` are executed in a subshell. When that exits you're still in the parent of `src`.

Answer (score 0):

ant performs smart building logic, it will not build a class unless the source was modified.

You might also like to look into scons which is not a native Java build tool but is very handy at compiling efficient complex build trees and does have java builder as well.

Comment: I used to use ant, but it's too slow.  I've hacked together my own build tool, which cuts compile time from 5000ms to 250ms (on average).  This question is about a refinement that should only add a few ms to that. I just looked at scons, but it doesn't have performance figures in the faq. I'll keep an eye on it though; thanks.

Comment: I just tried scons; it generates javac commands, which isn't what I need.  Also, I had a lot of trouble configuring it: the examples from the manual and `man scons` don't work as is, and in the end it couldn't find javac to compile.  Even though I configured the Environment with the tool 'javac' and passed in the JAVA_HOME env variable.  I mention this because I'm guessing it doesn't get a lot of use as a java tool, considering ant, IDE's and it's written in python. Finally, the fastest run I got was 1121ms (that's generating the javac command, not running it). Faster than ant, but not for me.